# How to view connection pool activity within Snowflake re: Looker?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connection-pooling, looker

we're trying to use connection pooling with Looker (BI tool) and Snowflake to reduce connection overhead of course.

Is there a way to view how many connections are open over a given time period for ... say a particular Snowflake warehouse? -- And how many queries are run over said period, and the typical lifespan?

I'm somewhat new to this topic. I'm thinking the connection pooling is managed at the application level (in this case Looker) which uses a Java-based driver to do so. And we're getting issues with "invalid state: closing connection when query still running." ... I guess what I'm asking is -- how do I diagnose and make sure connection pooling is working as intended?

Does Session ID within account_usage.query_history call out a particular 'connection' in Snowflake? But then how do I suss out the configuration and behavior of a specific 'pool' of connections?

Comment: A session id equates to a single connection to Snowflake so that’s probably what you need